# FPGA mining setup with Altera DE2-115

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, fpga

I have an Altera DE2-115 FPGA and I want to try mining. I found this project
https://github.com/progranism/Open-Source-FPGA-Bitcoin-Miner/tree/master/src
but when I try to start it, it says

`ERROR: Unable to getwork. Reason: key "result" not known in dictionary`

I have registered with bitminter.com for a url and I provide the url like this in the config file

```
# Edit this with your details and save as config.tcl
# They are the same worker server, user/pass you use
# with other mining software.
#
set url "http://eu1.bitminter.com:443"
set userpass "rtz:123"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially no software supports the `getwork` call anymore due to the speed of modern miners (they would call it 25,000+ times a second). You’ll need to use a very old version of Bitcoin Core from before this was removed if you’d like your software to work, but the FPGA miner is inefficient enough to never make this worth the time investment. The specific error you’re seeing from the miner is due to endpoint being removed from bitminter, and it not knowing how to handle the non response.